# XSLT convert current date to iso_8601

Tags: xslt

I was wondering if it was possible to convert a current date format to an ISO_8601 format using XSLT.

In the XML the date currently is set to:

```
<end_date>
<![CDATA[ 2015-10-14 23:59:59 ]]>
```

Comment: Please show an exemple of  ISO_8601 format. Help people to help you

Comment: 2015-10-14T23:59:59Z

Comment: @AdnaanAli Your source does not have a time zone or a time offset, so appending "Z" to the result cannot be considered "conversion".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example,

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(normalize-space(end_date), ' ', 'T')"/>
```

will return:

```
2015-10-14T23:59:59
```

This is a valid ISO 8601 representation of date and *local* time.

**If you are sure that the given value is in UTC** (although I don't see any such indication in your input) , and you want to indicate this in the result, you could do:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(translate(normalize-space(end_date), ' ', 'T'), 'Z')"/>
```

to return:

```
2015-10-14T23:59:59Z
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a XSLT that does the work :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                  xmlns:i="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Uanet>"
                      >
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="end_date">
      <!--copy current node-->
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="text()" />
      </xsl:copy> 
    </xsl:template>

    <!--
    input : 2015-10-14 23:59:59 
    output : 2015-10-14T23:59:59Z 
    -->
    <xsl:template match="text()">
      <xsl:variable name="trimmed" select="." />
      <xsl:value-of select="substring($trimmed,0,12)" />
      <xsl:text>T</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="substring($trimmed,13,8)" />
      <xsl:text>Z</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

  </xsl:stylesheet>
```